# Spring TransactionManager - commit does not work

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, spring-batch, transactionmanager

I am trying to create Spring-based solution for running batch of SQL queries on MySQL 5.5 server.
By "query" I mean any SQL statement that compiles, so the SQL batch job can contain for example several CREATE TABLE, DELETE and then INSERT statements.

I am using [Spring Batch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/) for this purpose.

I have `transactionManager` configured as follows.

```
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

and the `dataSource`:

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${batch.jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${batch.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${batch.jdbc.user}" />  
    <property name="password" value="${batch.jdbc.password}" /> 
    <property name="maxIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="100" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="10000" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="false" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1200000" />
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" />
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="5" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true" />
</bean>
```

My DAO class has the method configured with

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

and I loop over a collection of the SQL statements calling the method with single SQL statement a time.
The processing inside the method is as simple as:

```
simpleJdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().execute(sql);
```

I expected that when the DAO method completes, I would see the results in the DB.
However, it seems like only when the Spring job execution completes the results become available in the DB.

I tried to do the commit inside my DAO method:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
private void executeSingleQuery(String sql) {
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager = (PlatformTransactionManager)context.getBean("transactionManager");


    DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    def.setPropagationBehavior(Propagation.REQUIRED.ordinal());

    TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);

    try {
        // execute your business logic here
        log.info("about to execute SQL query[" + sql + "]");
        simpleJdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().execute(sql);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("SQL query  was not committed due to exception and was marked for rollback");
        transactionManager.rollback(status);
    }

    transactionManager.commit(status);

    if (transactionManager.getTransaction(null).isRollbackOnly() 
            && transactionManager.getTransaction(null).isCompleted()) {
        log.info("SQL query commited!");
    } else {
        log.info("SQL query  was not committed due to: 1) the transaction has been marked for rollback " +
                "2) the transaction has not completed for some reason");
    }

    log.info("the query has completed");
}
```

I debugged the Spring code and saw that the commit I call from my DAO method is executed by  TransactionTemplate (the flow reaches the line `this.transactionManager.commit(status);` and passes without exceptions)

I would appreciate any advice what should be done in order to make the DAO method to commit on every call (commit after every SQL statement it executes).

Comment: @Transactional annotation takes care of committing. In your code you don't need reference to transaction manager and commit the change explicitly, I suppose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot proxy private methods. i.e. The @Transactional you have here has no effect. Pull the method to your parent interface and it should work. Unless you have the proxyTargetClass setting enabled which is not recommended.

Comment: changed DAO method to public - same problem

Comment: pulling up the method to the parent interface helped the situation. Shukran! :)

Answer (score 3):

When you call your `executeSingleQuery()` from within the same class you are not going via the proxy so the transactional annotation will have no effect.

You are mixing declarative and programmatic transactions, Presumably you want `REQUIRES_NEW` so you could remove the pointless `@Transactional` annotation and use `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` when setting up your `DefaultTransactionDefinition`.

Also, you might want to move `transactionManager.commit(status)` inside the `try` block, your current code rolls back, then attempts a commit when an `Exception` occurs.

Comment: Thanks, I upvote your answer because it was helpful (part of it). However I cannot accept 2 answers -and MadheTo was the 1st to answer...

Answer (score 1):

We used the `@Rollback(value = false)` annotation and that fixed the issue you are facing.